# Chain Length 11-34 cassette

Tags: shimano, chain

I am looking to replace my 11-30 Shimano 8000 to 11-34 hg800 cassette. My current chain is 108 links with my 11-30 and works fine. Would this be long enough for the 11-34 cassette without changing the chain (its new anyway)?

My crankset is 52-36 and my chainstay length is 405mm. I have seen online calculators and they say 108 links, I want to make sure if this correct?

Comment: Generally, a new chain would be used if installing a new cassette as a worn chain on a new cassette will wear the cassette out prematurely (and a worn cassette will wear a new chain prematurely).  Only reason not to would be if you had a near new chain on an unworn cassette.  It might be prudent to change the chain anyway.

Comment: How worn is your current chain?   Are you trying to re-use it because it is almost new?   When you originally sized it, did you save the take-off links?

Answer (score 3):

It will also depend on the design of your derailleur. Any useful calculator would have to take that into account. But I'm sceptical of trying to calculate it. 4 teeth bigger on the big sprocket means an extra 2 teeth on the approximately semi-circular engagement, so 2 more links.

108 link chains are harder to find than slightly longer ones, so it's better to get a common 112 link chain and shorten it to fit. Or buy the cassette, see if the old chain is long enough, then buy the right new chain.

Assuming multiple chainrings, you should be able to cross-chain into the big/big combination that you wouldn't normally use, without the drivetrain jamming, but taking up essentially all the slack.

Comment: Its the MD R.D. Cage I have 8000 Utegra

Comment: The 108 link chain is the size I have on my bike  and its shimano 105 114 11 speed I have which was cut to size to 54 links (54x2=108) link chain.

Comment: Nobody can tell you. It's completely pragmatic. Look at your bike in big/big gear combo and see if you could remove another link without sproining the rear derailleur.

Comment: Dan this not about removing links if you read above I already have 108 links (54 links one side of the chain) running my 11-30 cassette. I trying to establish if my current chain setup will be enough length to cover 11-34 cassette I have the long RD U8000 cage. Also I have no intention of using the 34T on the big chain ring, will use it on the 36 chain ring for climbing steep and long climbs. However I will want to use it on 52 on the 30t 2nd clog down from the 34T  on lower climbs.

Comment: If you can guarantee that you'll never shift into the big sprocket while in the big ring, then why not just try it? It doesn't sound like you're due to replace your chain anyway. But for those of us who aren't infallible, the best way is to check. Really the best way to choose chain length is to by fitting and testing

Comment: +1 on this answer. Online calculators for this basically are ill-conceived for recent rear derailleurs; the rules for chain length used to be simpler. To OP: not intending to use the 52/34 is not relevant. What is relevant is how willing you are to break your bike if you shift into it by accident.

Comment: @DanGao chain links are one per tooth, because they're really half links but no one ever calls them that. Therefore you can't remove a single link, only a pair (aside from unusual parts used in dome singlespeed setups). So in that standard terminologu, you need 2 more links to go jalf way round the sprocket, as I said. You're right, that means they're not available elsewhere in that case. I have all the tools, and can size a chain, so you seem to be confusing me with the OP.

Comment: Apologies Chris, I was attempting to reply to Jon.H.  Jon., I'm not suggesting you remove anything. I'm pointing out that changing your cassette will eat up another link (two half links, Chris;-), so if you eyeball your current set up with one link squeezed out of the chainline, you can see how tight it wraps.  Never "intending to use" the big-big is different than never finding yourself there. However briefly. In the long run you will need chain tools sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks guys I will test it with the current setup of my chain and see how it goes. Now I checked ratios on the 11-30 and those ratios are on 11-34  in different sections of the clogs. This is how they go. 11-30/27/24//21/19/17/15/14/13/12/11   11/34/30/27/25/23/21/19/17/15/13/11.  My chain current setup will work on all those clogs. If I add another 2 links I may get chain slag on the lower ratios. It's just a question to try it out and see how it goes from 30 to 34 as it is big jump. To be honest I don't think it will be a issue.